# Debitoor API is returning 400 bad request

Tags: json, rest, api, post, jsonschema

I would like to create invoices by my PHP script. But before I am able to program this I would like to understand the API from Debitoor.

In order to create an invoice you have to create a draft invoice first. You can find this here: [/api/sales/draftinvoices/v3](http://developers.debitoor.com/api-reference#post-/api/sales/draftinvoices/v3).

I have set all the requested parameters to use the the /api/sales/draftinvoices/v3 function however, I always get a 400 Bad Request response back.. The reason is the schema.

Can you guys tell me where my failure is?
I would guess is something with the "lines"... but I would say it's all correct...

This is my request:
[image]

Request as text:

```
{
  "date": "2018-05-06",
  "dueDate": "2018-05-13",
  "notes": "Diese Rechnung ist vom Backend erstellt worden.",
  "customerName": "Max Mustermann",
  "customerAddress": "Mustermann Stra\u00dfe",
  "customerCountry": "DE",
  "currency": "EUR",
  "languageCode": "de-DE",
  "recargoTaxEnabled": false,
  "sent": false,
  "viewed": false,
  "displayAsPaid": false,
  "lines": {
    "taxEnabled": "false",
    "description": "Leistungszeitraum 06.04.2018 - 05.05.2018",
    "taxRate": "1.19",
    "productOrService": "product"
  }
}
```

This is the response I get back:
[image]

As text:

```
{
  "message": "Error validating against schema",
  "id": "9905636b-fb65-41a0-8d25-4aa096d5347d",
  "code": "schema",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "is the wrong type",
      "value": {
        "taxEnabled": "false",
        "description": "Leistungszeitraum 06.04.2018 - 05.05.2018",
        "taxRate": "1.19",
        "productOrService": "product"
      },
      "type": "array",
      "property": "lines"
    }
  ],
  "body": {
    "date": "2018-05-06",
    "dueDate": "2018-05-13",
    "notes": "Diese Rechnung ist vom Backend erstellt worden.",
    "customerName": "Max Mustermann",
    "customerAddress": "Mustermann Stra\u00dfe",
    "customerCountry": "DE",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "languageCode": "de-DE",
    "recargoTaxEnabled": false,
    "sent": false,
    "viewed": false,
    "displayAsPaid": false,
    "lines": {
      "taxEnabled": "false",
      "description": "Leistungszeitraum 06.04.2018 - 05.05.2018",
      "taxRate": "1.19",
      "productOrService": "product"
    }
  }
}
```

Kind regards and Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using the Debitoor API

You are correct. Your problem is with the lines. Lines should be an array. You have only send a single object.

Another issue is that you provide `taxEnabled: false` and `taxRate: 1.19`. If you provide `taxEnabled` as `false` you should set the taxRate to 0. Remember that taxRate should be between 0 and 100 with a maximum of two decimals

Your request should look something like this instead:

`{
 "lines": [
  {
   "taxEnabled": false,
   "description": "Leistungszeitraum 06.04.2018 - 05.05.2018",
   "taxRate": 0,
   "quantity": 1,
   "unitNetPrice": 1,
   "productOrService": "product"
  }
 ]`

Best regards,

Carsten

Mobile developer @ Debitoor